# unable to catch this error "Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError"

Tags: sequelize.js

I can create child record but what if not exist parent? this throw error which not able to catch in query catch with mysql DB.

but not able to catch this exception **Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED.**
here is my code

```
models.sequelize
.authenticate()
.then(function () {

    console.log('Connection successful');
    res.send("connected")
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating connection:", error);
    res.send(error)
});
```

i am only able to catch here but then how to response to user in this section?

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", function(reason, promise) {
//only able to handle here but not able to send this error in reponse

});
```

Although I used express Error handler but it still crash the application

Answer (score 1):

This is an open bug in sequelize

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1854

You can listen 'on' event on connection to handle error when connection is closed

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/2557

Comment: @Kaval bro but I also not able to catch foreign key error too.i just put this because any error which occurs in the module not able to catch.

Comment: Are you getting foreign key errors on connection or on query

Comment: yeah foreign key error. let me update the question. but i am also looking for catching server error too, incase mysql stop